# Parsing JSON rest api response in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Currently I have a Kubernetes environment and using Py rometheus toolkit for monitoring. I have application counters which are not exposed in container metrics. However I am able to view them as a JSON object by using a curl command.

http://10.0.0.1:8081/api/events/

I have used NodePort to expose POD externally via worker nodes's IP.

Response has the following format:

```
{
{
  "ID":   "001",
  "source": "pageloads",
  "summary":  "high failure counts",
  "severity": "major"
},
{
  "ID":   "003",
  "source": "profile_counts",
  "summary":  "profile count doesn't match number of groups",
  "severity": "minor"
},
{
  "ID":   "002",
  "source": "number of subscribers",
  "summary":  "profiles higher than subscribers",
  "severity": "critical"
}
}
```

Is there a way to include API response in Prometheus to poll every 15 seconds?

Comment: Are you asking how to configure Prometheus to scrape metrics from you app?

Comment: Yes, but without additional configuration on the application. Since I can already get the json response, can I configure prometheus to scrape the metrics?

Answer (score 5):

That json response is not in prometheus [format](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md) , hence prometheus will not be able to scrape that.You will need to use the language specific prometheus client library to instrument your code to expose metrics in prometheus format at /metrics endpoint.If that's not possible then you need to use an existing [exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) or write a custom exporter.This exporter runs as a separate process and will collect metrics from your application api endpoint and create prometheus format metrics and expose those metrics at /metrics endpoint.Then you can configure prometheus to scrape the exporter's /metrics endpoint.